# PHP regex modification

Tags: php, regex, joomla

I'm using an old Joomla! plugin (I know, first mistake). It does some URL replacement through regex. Here is the code:

```
$row->text = preg_replace_callback('@href=("|\')(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)("|\')@', 'replace_links', $row->text);
```

The problem is that it breaks with URLs that have a hyphen in them. Any help on how I can modify it to accept hyphens would be great.

It could also be the `replace_links` function that breaks:

```
function replace_links($matches) {
$match = $matches[0];
$array = array('href=',"'", '"');
$match = str_replace($array, '',$match);

if (strpos($match, JURI::root())) {
    return $matches[0]; 
} else {    
    $plugin =& JPluginHelper::getPlugin('content', 'linkdisclaimer');
    $pluginParams   = new JParameter( $plugin->params );
    $id = $pluginParams->get('disclaimerPage');
    $match = "href=\"javascript:linkDisclaimer('".rawurlencode($match)."', '".$id."');\"";
    return $match;  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this in a regex tester and it doesn't match urls with a - in them, so I'm guessing it's the regex. Try adding a - character into the regex like so `href=("|\')(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w-/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)("|\')`. This should allow - in the path segment after the domain. The full replacement would be like

```
$row->text = preg_replace_callback('@href=("|\')(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w-/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)("|\')@', 'replace_links', $row->text);
```